# Tkinter Grid column seperating too far

Tags: python, tkinter

The Grid for my code is separating too far and not working as I want them to. when I set it to 100 it stacks on each other and when I set it to 99 and 101 respectively, it goes to the opposite ends of each other.
I'm trying to put them beside each other at the center.

```
timbits = tk.Button(Donut, text="Timbits")
timdonuts = tk.Button(Donut, text="Donuts")
timbits.grid(column=80, row=6)
timdonuts.grid(column=120, row=6)
```

Comment: The result really depends on how the other widgets are laid out.

Comment: empty rows and columns have a height or width of zero.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do? Grid put the widgets in array style, so if you need to put buttons side by side, the left button needs the parameters row=0, column=0 and the right button needs row=0, column=1.